# How to query recursive MongoDB Document [File System of files and folders]

Tags: mongodb, recursion, filesystems, schema, typegoose

I am developing an application that uses MongoDB ([typegoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typegoose/typegoose)) to store file system-like (recursive) documents composed of files and folders. However, I do not know how to query such a schema. For querying, I am provided the following.

1. users _id
2. the array of folder names in order ex. ['root', 'nestedFolder1', 'nestedFolder2', 'etc...']
3. _id of the last folder chosen

The schema is as follows

```js
import { Types } from "mongoose";
interface File {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
    fileName: string;
    isDir: false;
    content: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
}

interface FileSystem {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
    folderName: string;
    isDir: true;
    files: File[] | [];
    folders: FileSystem[] | [];
}

interface Project {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
    projectName: string;
    fileSystem: FileSystem;
}
interface User {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
    projects: Project[];
}
```

Update:
Here's a replit for reference
https://replit.com/@alphacoma18/mongodb-recursive-schema#server.ts

Answer (score 0):

1- Most trivial query, get all FileSystem Documents:

```
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.find({
    // Empty Object means no condition thus give me all your data
});
```

2- Using the $eq operator to match documents with a certain value

```
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.find({

        isDir: true,
        folderName: { $eq: 'root' }
    });
```

3- Using the $in operator to match a specific field with an array of possible values.

```
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.find({
    isDir: true,
    folderName: { $in: ['root', 'nestedFolder1', 'nestedFolder2'] }
});
```

4- Using the $and operator to specify multiple conditions

```
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.find({
    $and: [
        { isDir: true },
        { folderName: { $in: ['root', 'nestedFolder1', 'nestedFolder2'] } }
    ]
});
```

5- Retrieve all documents that are directories and are not empty.

```
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.find({
    isDir: true,
    $or: [
        { files: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } },
        { folders: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }
    ]
});
```

6- All directories that have a folder name that starts with the letter 'n'

```
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.find({
    isDir: true,
    folderName: { $regex: '^n' }
});
```

Now the tougher queries:

1- count the total number of documents

```
const count = await FileSystem.aggregate([
    { $count: 'total' }
]);
```

2- count the total number of documents that are directories

```
const count = await FileSystem.aggregate([
    { $match: { isDir: true } },
    { $count: 'total' }
]);
```

3- Get 'foldername' and 'filename; of all documents that are files.

```
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.aggregate([
    { $match: { isDir: false } },
    { $project: { folderName: 1, fileName: 1 } }
]);
```

4-  Retrieve the total number of files (isDir: false) in each directory (isDir: true)

```
const fileCounts = await FileSystem.aggregate([
    { $match: { isDir: true } },
    {
        $project: {
            folderName: 1,
            fileCount: {
                $size: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$files',
                        as: 'file',
                        cond: { $eq: ['$$file.isDir', false] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

5- Recursive structure querying:
The FileSystem interface is recursive, because it has both an array of files and an array of folders, which are both of type File[] and FileSystem[].

To query this recursive schema, you can use the $lookup operator in an aggregate pipeline, to make a left join between FileSystem and itself, based on some criteria.

```
//Retrieve All Documents from FileSystem and their child documents
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'FileSystem',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'parentId',
            as: 'children'
        }
    }
]);

//Use the match operator in the pipeline to filter the results: 
const fileSystems = await FileSystem.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'FileSystem',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'parentId',
            as: 'children'
        }
    },
    { $match: { isDir: true } }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how can I just CRUD the nested files and recursive folders in the schema? I've updated the question and added a replit for reference.

Comment: You can use the mongoDB $lookup operator in an aggregate pipeline to perform a left outer join between FileSystem and itself. I will update the answer...

Comment: I think $lookup and $graphlookup are just for reading the recursive documents. But how about other operations such as `findOneAndUpdate` with `$push` for creating or updating and `findOneAndDelete` for deleting? An example would be in the case that I just want to update a file's contents that's nested within 5 folders or so

Comment: I believe that hard coding many `$elemmatch`, `.$.`, and `$[]` for each nest would not be great. That is why I have an array of the parent folders of the document to be updated in the order of their nest. But how do you dynamically code them or is there any other viable way?

Comment: The bounty expires in a few hours and there is no direct answer yet to the question. Fortunately, I found an alternate and better way to implement the schema and will be posting my answer soon. In the meantime, thanks for your answer and I'll be giving the bounty as I can't claim it back or receive it myself.